# In Visual studio how can I get my service reference to inherit from another class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, visual-studio-2012, service-reference

I'm struggling a bit with what I think should be quite simple and no amount of searching has provided me with any answers.

I am working on a WCF project in Visual Studio 2012 which makes use of a remote service reference.
This remote service reference uses WS-Security for message signature and data encryption and I would like to use Microsoft Web Service Enhancements 3.0 toolkit to help me with this but I can not find how to get my service reference to inherit from any of it's classes.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.